# Removing gap from top of QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlabel

I am showing image on my Qlabel. Right now its having a gap between the top of the window and top of the QLabel(image) like this :

[image]

I don't want that gap, my UI current UI is like this :

[image]

Where `label_image` is the object name for my QLabel containing the image.

My constructor code :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    this->setFixedSize(700,700);
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->setMargin(0);
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->setSpacing(0);

}

void MainWindow :: paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
    QMainWindow::paintEvent(e);
        if(1)
        {
           QImage image("/Users/arqam/Desktop/ImageToCartoon/input/ElonMusk.jpeg");
           //some redundant code
           ui->label_image->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
         }

}
```

Using the changes in `centralWidget` as shown I was able to get the image start from left most part, but am not able to get the image start from top.

Edit : What I need is my image to start from the `top left`, left part is done, just the top part is left.

My XML part of UI : https://pastebin.com/thxhc2Mj

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh sorry that was a part of redundant code, edited the code now. There I am scaling the image and then showing in QLabel, I guess that should not cause any difference.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yeah, basically I want the image to start from top left, so that the starting coordinate is same.

Comment: @eyllanesc There is some operation that I am doing in the paintevent, basically drawing some points on the coordinate and for that I want the Qlabel also to start from top left.

Comment: is it just me, or `label_image` appears to not be managed by any layout?

Comment: @Polentino I have edited the question with XML code also, there you can see that its under QVBoxLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To appear at the top use the [`setAlignment()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#alignment-prop), in your case

```
ui->label_image->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
```

Comment: Perfecto.
`I was earlier trying with ui->label_image->layout()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);`, thus not getting result.

Comment: One thing is the alignment of the layout and another is the alignment of the contents of the QLabel :P

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer.
While scaling QT sometimes turns the images in landscape mode : https://ibb.co/imSJSF
Any idea why this behavior happens?

Comment: I think the original image is like this, you can share the image in a zip so the internet does not change some bits, I have observed the same behavior when taking an image with the iphone, check the details of the image, not only based on your image viewer.

Comment: Yeah the image was taken by iphone itself, but I am seeing this mostly in those images which were too big to be resized and shown in the Qlabel. But still this does feel strange.

Comment: Some time ago a user asked me the same question, when I send it on the internet uploading to places as you used the problem was corrected when downloading, but when I send it zipped observe the same problem as yours, when verifying the dimensions of the Image I found that the image was rotated, ie the image viewer of the Mac rotated the images.

Comment: So its related to changes done in the image bits? Right now all my images are in the local storage itself.

Comment: Yes, I started to check the bits of the image header and realized that the bits that indicated the size were interchanged.

Comment: But in my case there is no interaction with Internet so why this problem is happening?

Comment: No, I do not think it explains well, what I want to tell you is that the iphone does not save the image correctly or does it with a format other than standard, and Qt uses the standard format of the images. What is the size of your image according to the MAC viewfinder?

Comment: The image that is changing its orientation it is `2320x3088` and when I resized it to `769x1024` it didn't change its orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and the xml file, I think a simple call to [QBoxLayout::addStretch()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) right after you add `label_image` should suffice. This will insert a [QSpacerItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html) in between the label and the horizontal layout that will keep the image on top, and the rest of the buttons at the bottom, even if you resize the widget.